# Iterating over the attributes of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, methods, attributes

is there any way to access the *sample_count* variable? I want to save the count of d,h,o,s to some variable to access it later.

Thanks.

```
a_train, a_test, b_train, b_test = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size = 0.30)

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'class': b_test,
                   'probability': range(1,158)}, columns=["class", "probability"])
sample_count=df_1.groupby("class").count()
print(sample_count)
```

[image: Output:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to iterate the over the values using the following code.

```
vals=sample_count.values
print(vals)
```

[image: Output:]